# Underscore Debounce Calling Multiple Times

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, debouncing

Calling `_.debounce()` causes the function to be executed multiple times instead of one time after they delay. How can I get the function within `_.debounce()` to be executed once after the specified delay? My use case is to perform an AJAX request after the user has stopped typing.

For example, typing into the input will cause a message to appear in the console after 1 second. In my example, you will see multiple messages appear (one for each letter you type). How would I modify my code to see only one message?

https://plnkr.co/edit/3dGm55ZFqWe4V59HLgoC

```
function onKeyUp() {
    _.debounce(() => {
        console.log('foo');
    }, 1000)();
}
<input onkeyup="onKeyUp()" />
```

Comment: Have you tried _.throttle() ?

Comment: @Radioreve I believe `_.throttle()` does the opposite of what I want. I am looking to perform an AJAX request after the user has finished typing. I believe `_.throttle()` would let me perform the AJAX request when the user begins typing, not when they have finished typing.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You are creating a new debounced function on every keyup event. Instead you need to create it once and use this function inside (or instead) onKeyUp event handler.

```js
var handler = _.debounce(() => {
  console.log('foo');
}, 1000)

function onKeyUp() {
  handler();
}
```

```html
<script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js"></script>
<input onkeyup="onKeyUp()" />
```

Comment: Is there a reason why `handler` is a variable and not a function? Ie: `function handler() {
   return (_.debounce(() => {
    console.log('foo');
  }, 1000));
}`

Comment: To clarify, is there a reason why `handler` is a function expression instead of a function declaration? How would I get the above code to work with `handler` as a function declaration?

Comment: @Jon [_.debounce()](http://underscorejs.org/#debounce) creates and returns a new debounced version of the passed function. And to be able to use this new function we need to store it somewhere. That is why it is stored as a variable. 

It will not work in your example with function declaration, because in this case each time, when you call `handler()` you will execute `_.debounce()` which leads to creating a new debaunced function instead of using it.

Comment: @Jon To be more precise, `handler` in my example is not a function expression. It's just a common expression like `var a = 5;`  Here is  [an example](https://jsfiddle.net/4sc9wL5t/14/) with some comments to clarify this.